# Almost diophantine equations?

Tags: tiling, diophantine-approximation, linear-diophantine-equations

Given square tiles of dimension 4.27" and 1.87" plus or minus .01" what grout widths are possible to make low order least common multiples?

Grout width can vary by 10% without being seen as different.

The idea is that N tiles of tile X + G (N-1) = M tiles of tile Y + G (M-1)

So that in a running pattern at least in one dimension NX tiles can be replaced by MY tiles. (There is always 1 less groutline than tiles.)

The goal is to find solutions where for a given pair of tile sizes X and Y, and a small range of G that M and N are small numbers.

This is not strictly speaking a diophantine equation, except that it is close to a diophantine equation in nature in that the desired solution is limited to integers, even though all the constraints are rationals.

I've been playing around it with a spreadsheet.

In general I've found less bad solutions if the tiles have a larger common factor f.  I'm bastardizing common factor here.  D = i * f where D is the dimension of the tile, and i is an integer.  f can be floating.  E.g. A 4.25" tile and a 1.75" tile have a common factor of 0.25, since both tiles are integer multiples of this.  I've also found less bad solutions when the grout width is either a divisor or a multiple of this common factor.

Is there a name for this class of problem?

What keywords do I need to look up to find better algorithms for finding solutions?

Warning:  Not a mathematician.  Be gentle.  I'm guessing at tags.  Feel free to adjust.

Comment: Interesting problem. Do you have a max or min grout width constraints?

Comment: Typically grout lines range from 1/16 for what they call registered tile (cut after firing so highly accurate dimensions) or for mosaics;  1/8 to 3/16 is common for wall tiles.  3/16 to 3/8 is common for floor tiles.  In general grout is small compared to tiles.   Tiles are not perfectly uniform.  One of the functions of grout is to fill in the irregularities.  With really rough tiles I've seen grout lines 5/8" wide.

Comment: What I'm trying to find is combinations that I can swap.  So for example if 24 blue tiles =  9 red tiles then I can replace any 24 blues in a row with 9 reds, and at the end come out even.  And the reds don't have be adjacent.  This opens up tiling patterns that look like cellular automata,or morse code encodings.

Comment: Grout width can vary by 10% of what?

Comment: Nominal width.  E.g. if its nominal width is 1/8" = .125" then it can differ by .012  , and not be noticeable.  So you could do one one kind of tile with .125 and one kind of tile at .137 and few people would notice.